# Native UIControls with jqTouch

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, jqtouch, cordova, uicontrol

After experimenting with a bunch of javascript tabbars (most fail when using forms), i've decided it might be a good idea to go native.

Would anyone know how to incorporate native UIControls (tabbar & header) in a jqTouch app.  I'd still need to retain control of the 'back' and 'info' buttons in the header.

Thanks!
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the best method to get this working, and thought I'd share the code.

So this is the combo: jQTouch + Phonegap = Native Tabbar that will work in unison with jQTouch.  Ie. When you click a tabbar icon, it will take you to the appropriate jQTouch page.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",setupToolbars);

function setupToolbars() {
 // Add these if you want the toolbar
 // window.uicontrols.createToolBar();
 // window.uicontrols.setToolBarTitle("Toolbar");

var activeTab;
activeTab = "#home"; // Better to have intro screen at home, and then make tab1 the first tab.

window.uicontrols.createTabBar();

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab1", "Tab1", "/www/images/tabs/yourimage1.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    myName = "#home"
    if (activeTab != myName)
    {
        jQT.goTo("#home", "fade");
        activeTab = myName;
    }
  }
});

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab2", "Tab2", "/www/images/tabs/yourimage2.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    myName = "#tab2"
    if (activeTab != myName)
    {
        jQT.goTo("#tab2", "fade");
        activeTab = myName;
    }
  }
});

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab3", "Tab3", "/www/images/tabs/yourimage3.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    myName = "#tab3"
    if (activeTab != myName)
    {
        jQT.goTo("#tab3", "fade");
        activeTab = myName;
    }
  }
});

 window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem("tab4", "Tab4", "/www/images/tabs/yourimage4.png", {
  onSelect: function() {
    myName = "#tab4"
    if (activeTab != myName)
    {
        jQT.goTo("#tab4", "fade");
        activeTab = myName;
    }
  }
});

 window.uicontrols.showTabBar();
 window.uicontrols.showTabBarItems("tab1", "tab2", "tab3", "tab4");
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for updating the buttons on the Navigation Bar?

Comment: Not just yet sorry... Currently i'm trying iScroll integrated, but am having a slight problem: http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/b54b3519391a0731

Answer (score 0):

What you need to determine at this point is what is the benefit of the hybrid approach? After you spend all of the time writing the native code to support the navigation and the tabs and the header bar you will have written a fair bit of code.

Then attempting to put that code together in a way to interface back to the Phonegap UIWebview it will, IMHO, become overly complex... however it can be done.

I woud suggest you first write the native application and get it functioning and then integrate that code back in to the PhoneGap Applicate Delegate

Here is a [complete tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/) that will be a good starting point